# Background image in XML

Tags: java, android

I'm using Android studio and I've setted a background image in this way :

android:background="@drawable/logo"

Error state that remove @ sign before "@drawable/logo

And the preview screen it's just white, on the phone app I can see the image perfectly.

While there is no problems with color and it also show in background in phone app.

I don't get it. What am I doing wrong? Also I've tried pressing 'R' on the preview view, but when the spinner finished, nothing happened.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your xml file here?

Comment: Please post your xml here

Comment: Image is :
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/image_login" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:srcCompat="@drawable/login" />

Comment: No, it gives massage that'The resource name must login with a character less...  validates with references inside Android XML Files.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on the line:

```
android:background="@drawable/logo"
```

This should be:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/logo"
```

you are missing the "android:" part before the drawable so it is incorrect format.

Comment: Nope. That means it's a system resource. That is, `android.R.drawable.logo`. There is no such drawable in the SDK, and I would imagine the OP is wanting to use their own image anyway.

Comment: No, it gives massage that'The resource name must login with a character less...  validates with references inside Android XML File

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your Android Studio and Gradle version and if older one, upgrade to new version.
2. Clean your project and close the project.
3. Reopen the project.

It will be working well.
Good luck.

Comment: It's android studio 3.1.1, No, it gives massage that'The resource name must login with a character less...  validates with references inside Android XML File